# Overlaying unique column values as geom_point in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here is an excerpt of the dataset I am working on.

```
Name    Value   ID  Total
   A      10    1   3
   A      11    2   3
   A      10    3   3
   B      10    1   4
   B      11    2   4
   B      11    3   4
   B      11    4   4
```

What I want to do is plot `Name` on the x-axis `ID` on the y-axis for all `Values` of `11`; on top of which I want to overlay `Total` so that when the graph is interpreted, it is possible to see the count of items per a Name group. This might be achieved using length of a group in the `Name` variable or using `Total`. Here is what I did and a sample of the output desired.

```
mydf <- read.csv("./test1.csv", header = T)
x <- ggplot(mydf, aes(Name, ID))+ geom_point(data = subset(mydf, Value==11), size=3, colour="tomato3")+  scale_y_continuous(name="Class ID", limits=c(1,4),breaks=seq(1,4, by=1))
y <- x+ xlab("Class")+theme_bw()
z <- y+scale_x_discrete(limits = c("A","B", "C"))
```

[image: Sample output]

The three orange asterisks at (A,3) and (B,4) are manual text annotation that I want to replace with either a short line or a circle to indicate the total number of items.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: If `ID` and `Name` are subject and/or group identifiers and `Total` is the value you want to plot, then maybe something like this would be better: `ggplot(mydf, aes(ID, Total)) + 
  geom_text(aes(label=Total)) +
  facet_grid(. ~ Name) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,4)) +
  theme_bw()`

Comment: Thank you @eipi10; I don't want to use facets as it will generate too many of them which will complicate making sense out of the graph. Just addition of `Total` in some form is what I want. Otherwise I will do manual annotation if it is not doable from either of `Total` or `Name` column.

Comment: If you want to annotate the total as a number, do something like: `library(tidyverse); geom_text(data = mydf %>% group_by(Name) %>% slice(1), aes(label=Total, y=Total), size=4, colour="black")`. To plot as a point marker, maybe this: `geom_point(data = mydf %>% group_by(Name) %>% slice(1), aes(y=Total), shape="\u2013", size=9, colour="black")`. ("\u2013" is the unicode en dash character (basically an elongated hyphen).)